# Total counts of a three-cell pattern in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm new to Excel. I want to identify/count the number of weekoffs (WO) between Absents (A).

Please see the image below:

[image]

Note that WO can appear between cells containing something other than A.  I want to count only cases where the surrounding cells both contain A.

In my example, I missed highlighting the WO for John in G2 and one for Rose in P3.  The desired result for this example would be 4 for John and 3 for Rose.

It is possible for there to be two consecutive weeks off between absences ( A--WO--WO--A ), so it would also be helpful to know how to count that pattern, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty straight forward to me:

Count WO, if to the left is A and to the right is A.

1. Add a row beneath each user: ie John
2. Row 3 Count John
3. Formulae:
   `=IF(AND(C2="WO",OFFSET(C2,0,-1)="A",OFFSET(C2,0,1)="A"),1,0)` and
   `=COUNTIF(C3:AG3,"<>0")`

[image]

> It is possible for there to be two consecutive weeks off between
>   absences ( A--WO--WO--A ), so it would also be helpful to know how to
>   count that pattern, as well.

This takes into account "CONSECUTIVE" variables. This I attack with another row in this example.

1. Row reserved for user: ie John
2. Insert row beneath John to count PATTERN.
3. Insert another row beneath John to count CONSECUTIVE patterns.

Number **2** -- reference above
 
New formula: **Pattern Counting**

`'=IF(OR(AND(G6="WO",OFFSET(G6,0,-1)="A",OFFSET(G6,0,1)="A"),AND(G6="WO",OFFSET(G6,0,1)="A",OFFSET(G6,2,0)="C")),1,0)`

Number **3** -- reference above

New formula: **Consecutives**
`'=IF(OR(AND(D11="WO",OFFSET(D11,0,-1)="WO"),AND(D11="WO",OFFSET(D11,0,1)="WO")),"C",0)`

[image]

---

**FINAL FORMULAE**

After consulting with the OP. Further analysis, to **count ALL WO's in-between A's** as follows:

[image]

The formulas to use (reference to above image):

**Row_1** 
`=IF(OR(AND(D31="WO",OFFSET(D31,0,-1)="WO"),AND(D31="WO",OFFSET(D31,0,1)="WO")),IF(OFFSET(D31,2,-1)>0,OFFSET(D31,2,-1)+1,1),0)`

**Row_2** 
`=IF(OR(AND(M31="WO",OFFSET(M31,0,-1)="A",OFFSET(M31,0,1)="A"),AND(M31="WO",OFFSET(M31,0,1)="A",OFFSET(M31,2,0)>0)),IF(OFFSET(M31,2,0)>0,OFFSET(M31,2,0),1),0)`

**Count** 
`=SUM(C34:AG34)`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50940/discussion-on-answer-by-ejbytes-total-counts-of-a-three-cell-pattern-in-excel).